# Why this error is taking place?

Tags: c++, string, recursion

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void printinter(string p1, string p2, int m, int n, string output, int i);
int main (void)
{
    string s1,s2,output="";
    cin>>s1>>s2;
    int m = s1.length();
    int n = s2.length();
    int i = 0;
    printinter(s1,s2,m,n,output,1);
    return 0;
}

void printinter(string p1, string p2, int m, int n, string output, int i)
{
    if (m == 0 && n == 0)
    {
        cout<<output<<"\n";
        return;
    }
    else if ( m!= 0)
    {
        //string foo = p1.substr(0,1);
        //cout<<foo<<"\t"; // used for debugging
        output = output + p1.substr(0,1);
        cout<<output<<"\t"; // used for debugging
        printinter(p1.substr(i,m),p2,m-1,n,output,i+1);
    }
    else if (n != 0)
    {
        output = output + p2.substr(0,1);
        printinter(p1,p2.substr(i,n),m,n-1,output,i+1);
    }
}
```

The above code basically is needed for printing all the interleavings of two strings `s1` and `s2`. Now, I initially take input in `s1` and `s2`, and pass it to the function `printinter` which through recursion prints the interleavings. Basically, it fixes first character, then recurses for the remaining characters, and then fixes the first character for the other string and recurses for the remaining characters and each time decrementing the length by 1 unit. In the end, it prints the output.

When I try to run it, it gives the error, `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string
Abort trap: 6`

Now, I am trying since the past two hours by placing `cout` statements at various places to find out the error. But nothing seems to work. On running with the debugger, somehow, it doesn't print `output` in the first iteration itself. I don't know why. I wouldn't have asked it here, but, I don't know what's the error. I usually debug the code myself, but help me with this one. Thanks!

Comment: It has too many errors for a simple answer.  Most severe is you aren't swapping the strings on the recursive call, so it won't alternate the way you wanted.  But because it doesn't alternate, the use of i as an index into the second string becomes wrong when i has been incremented by its use in the first string.

Comment: I suggest you simplify and either pass just substrings without indexes or pass unmodified original strings as well as indexes.  By modifying both the string and the index as you nest into the recursive call, you are doing want seems to be the same job twice and you seem to be confusing your intent.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised people are down-voting this without bothering to explain why.  If I had to guess, people are down-voting because the code is doing some strange / unsafe things, though now I'm putting words in their mouth.

The documentation for [std::string::substr()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) says this:

> If pos is greater than the string length, an out_of_range exception is thrown.

Each recursive call shrinks the size of the string being passed along because `substr()` allocates a new string object:

> Returns a newly constructed string object with its value initialized to a copy of a substring of this object.

... but `i` continues to grow until it exceeds the length of the strings being passed in.

Comment: Solved. I used pointers to a char array instead of strings. Strings seem to be too difficult to work with in this case. However, can you tell me what correction should I do in order to make it work with strings?

Comment: Whatever you did with pointers to char arrays should be trivially convertible to strings.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how your original code even tried to do something like the following.  But your description of what you want to do seems to be the following.  Is this what you meant?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void printinter(string p1, string p2,string output);
int main (void)
{
    string s1,s2,output="";
    cin>>s1>>s2;
    printinter(s1,s2,output);
    return 0;
}

void printinter(string p1, string p2, string output)
{
    if (p1.length())
    {
        if (p2.length())
        {
            printinter(p1.substr(1),p2,output+p1[0]);
            printinter(p1,p2.substr(1),output+p2[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << output+p1 << '\n';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << output+p2 << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were trying for something like this, but just made things more complicated than they need to be.  If that isn't what you meant, then you might clarify.  Any of the extra complexity (such as the output string) that you might have actually had a reason for, could be easily added back to this simplified version without breaking it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void printinter(string p1, string p2);
int main (void)
{
    string s1,s2,output="";
    cin>>s1>>s2;
    printinter(s1,s2);
    return 0;
}

void printinter(string p1, string p2)
{
    if (p1.length())
    {
        cout << p1[0];
        printinter(p2, p1.substr(1));
    }
    else
    {
        cout << p2;
    }
}
```

Comment: No no, the thing is, your code prints just one of the output. I have to print all the interleavings, where an interleaving of two strings is a string which has all characters of both the strings and relative order of characters in the new string is same as the original string.

Comment: Moreover, I did the exact same thing with pointer to char arrays method, and it works but not the above with substrings. There must be some error with finding a substring, I guess.